# Adding numbers with recursion in a pyramid form

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, stack

I have this given Array `{1,2,3,4,5}` and I should create an output like this with recursion:

```
48
20 28
8 12 16
3 5 7 9
1 2 3 4 5
```

I have to add the value of `[i]` with the value of `[i+1]`. In the end it should have a form of a pyramid.

This is my code:

```java
package Übungen;

public class Symmetrie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //0 is just a placeholder to avoid an error in line 21
        int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
        int j = 5;
        reku(b, j);
    }

    public static void reku(int[] num, int j) {
        System.out.println("");
        if (j > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                System.out.print(num[i] + " ");
                num[i] = num[i] + num[i + 1];
            }
            reku(num, j - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

It creates an output like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
3 5 7 9
8 12 16
20 28
48
```

I think I have to use the stack when I use the recursion. But I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

class Main {
    static List<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists =
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //0 is just a placeholder to avoid an error in line 21
        int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};  
        int j = 5;

        reku(b, j);
        Collections.reverse(listOfLists);
        for (List list : listOfLists) {
            System.out.println(list.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void reku(int[] num, int j) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (j > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                list.add(num[i]);
                //System.out.print(num[i] + " ");
                num[i] = num[i] + num[i + 1];
            }
            listOfLists.add(list);
            reku(num, j - 1);
        }
    }
}
```